# Azure SQL Database Corruption - Cannot delete with error 40613

Tags: sql-server, azure, dacpac, azure-sql-database

We have a windows service that provisions Azure SQL databases for our clients. We are using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql` API for this. Our service creates the SQL Server instance and deploys the schema using a DACPAC.

When running recently we received the following warning during the DACPAC deployment step:

> Warning - Database 'AG61_xxxxx' on server 'xxxxxx.database.windows.net' is not currently available.  Please retry the connection later.  If the problem persists, contact customer support, and provide them the session tracing ID of '{xxxxxxxx-C7D7-4504-AF25-4C3AC020BE90}'. (73144)

The problem we have is that this database is now left in an inconsistent state:

1. It isn't listed in the Azure Portal under databases.
2. The Azure API doesn't return it in list of databases on the server.

Attempting to recreate the same database on the same server, either via code OR via the Azure Portal, returns

> Database 'AG61_xxxxx' already exists. Choose a different database name.

However, I **can** log into SSMS as the admin user and see the database listed. If I try to delete it I receive the following error:

> Failed to connect to server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> Additional information:
>   Database 'AG61_xxxxx' on server 'xxxxxxxxxx' is not currently available.  Please retry the connection later.  If the problem persists, contact customer support, and provide them the session tracing ID of 'FBE26206-C3B6-4771-B0EF-4BCA9C154F28'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 40613)

According to [Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-troubleshoot-connection/), error **40613** is transiant and should only last a few seconds. We've been unable to do anything with this database for 3 days.

Has anyone else experienced this? I'd like to know if there is something we can do to recover the database on this server such that we don't have to have the client change their connection strings etc.

I'd also like to know if there is anything I could do in future to mitigate this happening again.